# OpenLayers Measure function crashing IE

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

Anyone experience any problems with IE crashing on an OpenLayers Measure call?

```
distCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.Measure(OpenLayers.Handler.Path, { persist: true, handlerOptions: { layerOptions: { renderers: renderer, styleMap: styleMap}} });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the patch:

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/2997

Comment: Was using Openlayers 2.10, updated to 2.11 and works great now in IE!

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting consistent feedback from my users that IE (even IE9) is not the best browser to use for OpenLayers code. Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari all handle it better.